# Bootstrap horizontal form input and selects don't right align

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The right hand sides of selects and inputs are not aligning in my bootstrap horizontal form. Based on my debugging, it looks like the inputs are overshooting the boundaries of the parent div, while the selects are well behaved and respect the boundary. How do I "convince" the inputs to align with the selects

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bjFXe/6/

CSS

```
input, select {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="accordion row-fluid" id="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#main">
                Main
            </a>

            <div id="main" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span6">
                                <div class="control-group warning">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="test1">test1</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <select id="test1">
                                            <option>option 1</option>
                                            <option>option 2</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="test2">Test2</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Test2" id="test2">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="span6">
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="test3">test3</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" id="test3">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group warning">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="test4">test4</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <select id="test4">
                                            <option>option 1</option>
                                            <option>option 2</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the `input-block-level` class on the input fields.  This will convert the inputs to block level, and as such they will take up all available space.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Test2" id="test2" class="input-block-level"/>
```

This class is part of the bootstrap framework, so you are not adding additional custom css.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know why this is happening. Looks like a padding/margin issue. However, setting absolute values works:

```
input, select {
    width: 12;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: By not specifying the unit with the `width`, you run the risk of the browser ignoring the statement.  This seems to be what is happening when applied to the orginal poster's fiddle.  To confirm, you can simply remove the `width` statement and you will still get the same results.